# Combine two Google spreadsheet together and keep it sync

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheet from others and wish to create another one which combine both sheet together.

e.g.

SheetA:

```
Name value
A     10
B     20
```

SheetB:

```
Name value
C    30
D    40
```

Then I want to create one SheetC:

```
Name value
A     10
B     20
C     30
D     40
```

And if I change SheetC, I wish data synced to SheetA or SheetB automatically.

Comment: The first part of your question mostly makes sense, but the last bit doesn't at all. Sheet C can be used to consolidate the values from both A & B, but if you then enter values on C, where would you expect them to show up - on A or B?

Comment: Of course, I wish if data belong to A, then re-flash A, if data belong to B, then re-flash B.

Comment: You can't really say "of course" because you haven't detailed how you'd like that to work :) Could you explain how you want to 're-flash' the data sources? Step through it like the user would

Comment: I guess we can do it by GAS, when data changed, then trigger the function to send data to remote, from the remote, we need to do the same thing but need to match the cell location correctly. still not figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can implement the doc combine with below script:

```
function runme() {
  var docA = "<Doc Id A>";
  var docB = "<Doc Id B>";
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  appendSheet(docA,sheetName);
  appendSheet(docB,sheetName);
}

function appendSheet(docId,sheetName) {
  var sourceSpread = SpreadsheetApp.openById(docId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpread.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  var activeSpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSpread.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();

  sourceRng = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  sourceRows = sourceRng.getValues(),

  activeSheet.appendRow(sourceRows[0]);
  for (i = 1; i < sourceRows.length; i += 1) {  
    activeSheet.appendRow(sourceRows[i]);
  }
  Logger.log("total: " + i);
}
```

But it seems it's difficult to sync information from docC to docA and docB.